# How do I suppress Undertow stack traces?

Tags: exception, undertow

I have a running HTTP server using Undertow in an embedded fashion. One thing I cannot figure out how to do is to prevent Undertow (or XNIO) from polluting the console log with useless IOException stack traces when the client abruptly disconnects during transmission.

What I want to do is emit a one-line note, only if diagnostics are enabled, that a connection ended with an exception and which handler was executing when that occurred. There is no recovery, of course, just note the fact and move on.

Unfortunately, these appear to be caught and dumped deep in the bowels of Undertow (or XNIO)code; catch clauses in my code never see these exceptions, so they have been swallowed before control returns to my handler.

Comment: These stack traces are logged by a logger, or directly dumped on stdout/stderr?

Comment: What log manager are you using?